# MSSQL2014 & python 3.7.3: Trying to get stored procedure return value results in "No results. Previous SQL was not a query."

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I'm running a python script which connects to a MSSQL database, runs a stored procedure and should take a some actions depending on the stored procedure return value. Here's the code:

```
'''
sql = """\
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @rv INT
        EXEC @rv = [MY_DB].[dbo].[sp_Load_Actuals]
        SELECT @rv 
        """
...
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
                                      'Server=MY_SERVER;'
                                      'Database=MY_DB;'
                                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
retv = cursor.fetchone() 
...
```

On the execution of the last statement I'm catching the **pyodbc.DatabaseError** exception with the message  ***"No results. Previous SQL was not a query."*** I have read all related articles here, but apparently I'm still doing something wrong.

What do I miss?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the source code of your stored procedure. Presumably the stored procedure deletes, inserts or updates some data - does it start with `SET NOCOUNT ON`?

Comment: Right. It calls three other sp's and all four of them start with SET NOCOUNT ON. Besides I have commented out all debugging prints. This is a quite old legacy SQL and I'm not an SQL guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `cursor.nextset()` to skip past any info messages that were output by the called stored procedures, as NOCOUNT ON is not enough here.

But unfortunately `cursor` doesn't have a `.hasrows()` method, so you have to catch the exception in a loop.

EG:

```
import pyodbc


sql = """\
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE @rv INT
        EXEC @rv = sp_executesql N'print ''informational message'''
        SELECT @rv 
        """

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                                      'Server=localhost;'
                                      'Database=tempdb;'
                                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)

while True:
    try:
        retv = cursor.fetchone() 
        break
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as e:
       if "Previous SQL was not a query." in str(e):
        if not cursor.nextset():
          throw

print(retv)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot.